# How many units does one account have

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We have a solution with millions of users and we expect this number to keep rising.

One important feature that we want to deliver is a gallery of videos from specific channels from Youtube.

We expect to make millions of calls to the Youtube API to show these videos and we want to avoid hitting the daily limit.

[YouTube Data API Overview](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota)

In the above article is stated that we have 200k max daily limit for read.

The question is if this is a hard limit or is this flexible with a pricing model for consumption plan or is it scaled in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

New accounts have 10k quota units. Each API call will consume one or more units, you can find each operation cost in API reference. There is no any pricing model (at least public), but you can ask Youtube support for more quota units. You can cache requests. You can even have up to 20 api keys per account, and each have 10k youtube api quota units.

Comment: hummmm the API keys perhaps might help me, but i would need to control the usage somehow.

Comment: about the cost per request, yes i have simulated that in the documentation, i would consume 3 units each time.

Comment: @Zorkind you will get specific error message, when quota is exhausted, so you can switch to next key. Also it worth a try to ask for more quota.